# Girl Becomes Captain of College Team Her Mother Captained

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have seen a movie 2-3 weeks ago and I do not know the title. I even forgot to check for the title. I do not know the name of any actor, but I remember the plot.

So, the movie talks about a girl, whose mother dies when the girl is 11 years old. Her dad takes her to a college in the UK. She does not want to stay there and tries to get out of the school. Her roommates help her. After she achieves her mission, she wants to stay and not leave and she becomes the captain of the college in a sport where her mother was also the captain in 1976. 
The college accepted only female students.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like [Wild Child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Child_%28film%29) from 2008. From an online [synopsis](http://www.filmink.com.au/reviews/wild-child-dvd/):

> Poppy (Emma Roberts) is a Malibu barbie in miniature whose misadventures cause her father (Aidan Quinn) to send her to boarding school in England to eradicate her aggressive impulses [...] After a series of mishaps and wacky coincidences, she becomes captain of the Lacrosse team and ends up as an angel that was hidden inside all along.

She discovers at some point that her (deceased) mom was also the school's Lacrosse team captain. Here's the trailer: